# Set margin size when converting from Markdown to PDF with pandoc

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I have created an RMarkdown file in RStudio and managed to knit it with knitr into an HTML and .md file.  Next, I used pandoc to convert the .md file into a PDF file (I get an error if I try and convert from the .html file).  However, the PDF that is produced have massive margins (like this http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example13.pdf).  How can I get pandoc to produce something with smaller margins?  I have looked through the pandoc user guide, but haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 378, accepted):

#### Recent versions of rmarkdown and pandoc

In more recent versions of **rmarkdown**, the settings of margins can be done in the YAML header via the top-level element `geometry`. What you specify in the `geometry` tag will be piped into the LaTeX template that ships with Pandoc via the following LaTeX snippet

```latex
$if(geometry)$
\usepackage[$for(geometry)$$geometry$$sep$,$endfor$]{geometry}
$endif$
```

For example, to specify margins that are 2cm in width one would include

```yaml
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
geometry: margin=2cm
output: pdf_document
---
```

For more complex specifications to be passed to the **geometry** LaTeX package, string options together as you would with LaTeX:

```yaml
---
title: "Habits"
author: John Doe
date: March 22, 2005
geometry: "left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
output: pdf_document
---
```

---

#### Original answer

This is a LaTeX question as Pandoc is rendering to PDF via LaTeX - what you linked to represents the default margins on a LaTeX document.

The **geometry** LaTeX package for example can be used to alter the margins of the page. However you'll need a way to tell Pandoc to use this by including it ins the LaTeX header applied to the converted md file.

How you do this is documented in the [Pandoc User Guide](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html). See in particular the `--template=FILE` command line argument and the [Templates section](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates). Essentially, either find and modify the default template to include the LaTeX instructions you want to use or start your own template from scratch and place it in the appropriate location; see the `--data-dir` command line argument.

---

Another alternative if you are using a recent version of Pandoc is to use the variable argument (set either with `-V KEY[=VAL]` or `--variable=KEY[:VAL]`). The `geometry` package was added to the default LaTeX template in May 2012 (see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/59mBEixlIJU/discussion)). As such, if you wanted to change the page margins, you can use:

```
pandoc -V geometry:margin=1in -o output.pdf input.md
```

You can specify multiple variable values too. For instance, if you wanted to create a 4 by 6 inch pdf with half-inch margins, you can use:

```
pandoc -V geometry:paperwidth=4in -V geometry:paperheight=6in -V geometry:margin=.5in -o output.pdf input.md
```

Comment: If you are using the latest version of Pandoc, you can also set this using the `variable` command instead of having to make a template from scratch or hard-coding the margins in the default template. For example, for 1 inch margins, you can use `pandoc -V geometry:margin=1in -o output.pdf input.md`.

Comment: @mrdwab That is exactly what I need.  Thanks a lot.  Want to post that as an answer so I can Accept it?

Comment: @mchangun, I've edited Gavin's answer to include my comment since it is a valid one that might be useful for users who want to use other custom LaTeX packages not included in the default Pandoc templates.

Comment: Very new to pandoc. I was finding that the `-V geometry:margin=1in` option was having no effect. Via googling, I found somewhere (sorry lost the link) documentation saying that this option has no effect if using the default template.  I just want to convert a one page markdown file to a PDF to send to someone as a flier. My quick solution: Edit the template file directly and add the line `\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}`. On my install, the file is in: `/usr/share/pandoc-1.9.1.1/templates`

Comment: Is there a way, from the command line to affect just one of the margins?  My entire book has a giant gap at the bottom and I just want to affect that margin.  -V geometry:margin:bottom doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AustinFatheree I've updated the answer to address your question. It is easiest to do this via the new(ish) `geometry` element in the YAML metadata.

Comment: Does not seem to work for `pandoc 2.9.2.1` when using `--pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: @twitu I guess there is no LaTeX involved in that conversion of HTML to PDF. I would suggest you ask a new question as that seems a more unique and specific request than the question posed here originally. I had a quick look and I couldn't see anything that immediately jumped out at me where one could configure things like this, but I'd start with wkhtml itself to see what customisation is possible

Comment: @twitu oh, actually missed this on first pass. See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-wkhtmltopdf and I think you will need to pass this via the V mechanism, so in rmarkdown that would be via the pandoc_args element of the YAML header. (not tested). If you can throw together a minimal example I post a new Q I can take a closer look? (just link it here in a comment)

Comment: This is the solution that finally worked for me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040862/pandoc-and-html5-exporting-pdfs-with-huge-margins/54584490#54584490

Comment: When i set geometry margins it moved only the title and author but it did not include the kable tables i added in the pdf as well.

Answer (score 125):

In more recent versions of pandoc, you can set a number of parameters in the [YAML header](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block). You can set the geometry here, for example:

```
---
title:  Pandoc nice margins example
author: naught101
geometry: margin=3cm
---

body text of document
```

When pandoc converts it to a pdf, it should have correct margins.

Comment: This is a much better solution! It is quite useful when you are automatically building the document in an editor like `Kile` or `Sublime Text 2/3` and changing command line arguments would be a pain.

Answer (score 3):

FTR: "recent version" above seems to include Knitr 1.30, before I needed following header:

```
---
  pdf_document: null
  geometry: margin=1cm
  output: pdf_document
---
```

Without the additional `pdf_document: null` the geometry setting had no effect. With it, settings from https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-variables.html worked.