# Set double spacing and line numbers when converting from Markdown to PDF with pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I am using markdown & pandoc for scientific writing, I know I can change margins of the final pdf using

[Set margin size when converting from Markdown to PDF with pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515893/set-margin-size-when-converting-from-markdown-to-pdf-with-pandoc)

but very often the journals require double lines and line numbers in submitted manuscripts, the question is how to change these, I don't know much about LaTex so I am lost in that jungle.

Thanks!

Comment: LaTeX provides the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace), as well as [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno). I'm unfamiliar with Pandoc's interface or usage, so I'm of no help there. If this turns out to be a purely TeX/LaTeX problem, consider flagging your own post and request migration to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com). Don't repost there; rather flag for migration.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is maybe an easy way: generate a file with the packages we need

```
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \doublespacing
 \usepackage[vmargin=1in,hmargin=1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{lineno}
 \linenumbers
```

I named it options.sty. And use the -H FILE option that includes the content of the FILE at the end of the preamble. (as used in https://github.com/karthikram/smb_git)

```
 pandoc -H options.sty --bibliography mypaper.bib mypaper.md -o mypaper.pdf
```

The advantage is that we don't need to edit the template. To add linenumbers, change margins, and set spacing it works.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Output file follows -o. Deleted to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 39):

In more recent version of Pandoc, you can use a [YAML header](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) and include a bunch of metadata in that, instead of using options on the command line. So, for instance, you can put this at the top of your `.md` file:

```
---
title: The Document Title
author:
    - Your Name
    - Co Author
date: \today{}
geometry: margin=2cm
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}
    - \doublespacing
    - \usepackage{lineno}
    - \linenumbers
---

Document Text
```

and pandoc will read those options and apply them automatically.

Answer (score 13):

You'll need to use a custom LaTeX template.  First, use pandoc to create a copy of the default template:

```
pandoc -D latex > mytemplate.latex
```

Now edit this template.  Somewhere in the preamble (between `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}`), insert the lines

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

Then, to use your custom template:

```
pandoc --template mytemplate.latex mypaper.txt -o mypaper.tex
```

Comment: To add line numbers I read the `lineno` package documentation but can't figure out how to add them.