# Setting pandoc to PDF font size smaller than 10pt

Tags: pdf, font-size, pandoc

Does anyone know how I can change the font size used in pandoc to pdf smaller than 10pt? [The docs](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) seem to imply that 10pt is the smallest, but I figure that since it's calling the LateX engine it must be possible to get smaller fonts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it turns out this is a latex question.

Pandoc to PDF uses a Latex config file (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883525/set-double-spacing-and-line-numbers-when-converting-from-markdown-to-pdf-with-pa?rq=1)). To set fonts smaller than 10pt you'll need to specify a package ([see this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt)).