# create function to alter PDF margin width in PDF files using Pandoc

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm converting a markdown document to a PDF using Pandoc from within R. The default margins of PDFs outputted by Pandoc are too large.

In this post: [Set margin size when converting from Markdown to PDF with pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515893/set-margin-size-when-converting-from-markdown-to-pdf-with-pandoc), the following code is given to alter margin widths of PDFs:

```
pandoc -V geometry:margin=1in -o output.pdf input.md
```

I've using this code in a function from within R,

```
makePDF <- function(name) {
  library(knitr)
  knit(paste0(name, ".Rmd"), encoding = "utf-8")
  system(paste0("pandoc -o -V geometry:margin=1in ", name, ".pdf ", name, ".md"))
}
```

but this gives this error:

```
pandoc: geometry:margin=1inmpAnnual.pdf: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

How can I create a function in R to alter margin widths of PDFs?

Comment: IMHO you missed the `-o` part, but it would be a huge help if you would also share the exact error message.

Comment: question now edited: I've posted error, and I've also tried using -0

Comment: Your error mentions a `docx` file! Where did you pull that from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your `paste0` construction does not create what you are after. Your error message also doesn't reflect the code you have provided.

```
name <- 'name'
paste0("pandoc -o -V geometry:margin=1in ", name, ".pdf ", name, ".md")
## [1] "pandoc -o -V geometry:margin=1in name.pdf name.md"
```

The you have put `-o` in the wrong spot.

I think it easier to use `sprintf` to create calls such as this, using `%s` for where you want to insert your file name.

```
callformat <-"pandoc -V geometry:margin=1in  %s.md -o %s.pdf"
sprintf(callformat, name,name)
## [1] "pandoc -V geometry:margin=1in  name.md -o name.pdf"
```