# avoid setting margin via geometry

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

When using

```
render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_book")
```

it looks like a line setting the margins is inserted in the tex file

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

The `bookdown-demo` repro can be used to reproduce this.

In `index.Rmd`, I'm using

```
--- 
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
knit: "bookdown::render_book"
documentclass: krantz
classoption: numberinsequence,krantz1
bibliography: [book.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: yes
---
```

and this is goofing up the margins set by that style file. I know that I can [modify the geometry options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515893/set-margin-size-when-converting-from-markdown-to-pdf-with-pandoc) but can I just avoid this line being generated?

Thanks

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bookdown_0.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] backports_1.0.5 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2   htmltools_0.3.6
[5] tools_3.3.3     rstudioapi_0.6  yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.11   
[9] stringi_1.1.5   rmarkdown_1.5   knitr_1.16      stringr_1.2.0  
[13] digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10
```

Comment: What does your YAML look like at the top of your index file?

Comment: I've added that above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`documentclass: krantz` indicates that you are writing a book for Chapman & Hall, and I have provided [a starter repo `bookdown-crc`](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-crc) for such authors who use **bookdown** (the [`bookdown-demo`](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) repo is not the best option for you). Your issue does not exist in this repo because [I set `template: null` for `pdf_book` in `_output.yml`](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-crc/blob/20867f65/_output.yml#L24). The reason for this is that I wanted to use Pandoc's default template, which does not add the default `margin=1in` to the `geometry` option in YAML (and **rmarkdown** does -- that is the culprit).

If you do want to use **rmarkdown**'s LaTeX template (which is modified based on Pandoc's), you can set

```
geometry: false
```

in the YAML metadata of your `index.Rmd`.

For your reference, I have a section specifically for Chapman & Hall authors in the **bookdown** book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/publishers.html

Comment: Thanks; I'll model my setting on this new repo - Max

Answer (score 0):

The krantz.cls indeed provides the margin settings you need to use for CRC. I was tempted to use my own geometry margin setting, but it messes with the trim cuts, so it's best to let krantz.cls take care of it.  You do need to make sure everything fits, including output from code chunks, and tables can be problematic.

For kable tables, this was useful to avoid exceeding the margins:

```
knitr::kable(head(runoff), caption = '...', format="latex") %>% 
    kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down")
```

The hard part is getting things working for both html and latex/pdf, and I found this structure useful.

```
if (knitr::is_latex_output()){
  knitr::include_graphics(here::here("img","myscreenshot.png"))} else {
  `code for creating the output in html`
  }
```