# Visual Studio Code with pandoc

Tags: pdf, pandoc

I would like to create PDF-files from MD-files (Markdown) with pandoc. But I don't find a place where I can define the `page-margin`s for the PDF-document.

I think there must be a place where I can define the PDF-settings including the `page-margin`s. What can I do to set them?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13515893/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set margin size when converting from Markdown to PDF with pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515893/set-margin-size-when-converting-from-markdown-to-pdf-with-pandoc)