# Is there a way to customize margins in yaml rticles, R

Tags: r-markdown, margins, article

I am trying to use the `elsevier_article` template in `rticles` package in R to write an article. I am curious about whether I can customize the margins in the `yaml` header in the Rmarkdown file? I personally think the current margin is too wide.

I guess I do not need to provide a reproducible example here since I am not debugging the code for an error.

Comment: Try the `geometry` parameter as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13516042/1777111)

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Got it. That solves my question and I have merged the two questions. Thanks a lot!